# Initialize NSMutableArray

Tags: objective-c, xcode, uitableview, nsmutablearray, didselectrowatindexpath

Im very new in xcode 3 and i really need help for this

I developed my apps using UITableView and XML to showed the content.

i had 3 .xib files which it rootViewController , SecondViewController and mainview.

**So the problem is:**
When i try to executed didSelectrow in rootViewController and access the NSMutableArray *array in SecondViewController and replace the *array value with new array value in rootViewController before pushed animation.

The array value on my SecondViewController was changed for the first time but when i pushed the back button and select the other row, my SecondViewController array kept read the previous array not change to a new one. I try to initialize but no luck

This is my code on rootViewController UITableview (didSelectRow):

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    if(2ndController == nil)

2ndController = [[DetailViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"SecondViewController" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];

    //Declare xml NSMutable array record
    ListRecord *record = [self.entries objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    //access SecondViewController NSMutable *record
    2ndController.record = [[[NSMutableArray alloc] init] autorelease];   

        //inserting the value from firstview to secondview before push
    2ndController.record = record;



    //push animation
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:2ndController animated:YES];



}
```

This is my second view controller :

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tv cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];
    }

    switch(indexPath.section)
    {
        case 0:

            [cell setText:record.name];
            break;
        case 1:

            [cell setText:record.Age];
            break;
        case 2:
        [cell setText:record.summary];
            break;
    }

    return cell;
}
```

Hope someone can help me..

Thanks in advance.....

Comment: So ListRecord is a subclass of NSMutableArray? I'm confused, because you said you're setting an array, but it looks like you're actually setting the property 'record' which is of type ListRecord*

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Few things,

You do,

```
2ndController.record = [[[NSMutableArray alloc] init] autorelease];
```

and follow it up with

```
[cell setText:record.name];
```

Clearly, the `record` property doesn't seem to be an instance of `NSMutableArray` so I think the array initialization part is incorrect as you do, and already mentioned,

```
2ndController.record = record;
```

But the problem I think is that you are retaining your `UITableViewController` subclass. Have you tried reloading the data?

```
[self.tableView reloadData];
```

Add it in the `viewWillAppear` method of your `DetailViewController`.

Comment: Thanks men.... Reload Data is the function that i was seek....and for initialization.. i just tried and error.. i knew it was wrong.. thanks again : )

Answer (score 1):

You should look at these two lines again:

```
2ndController.record = [[[NSMutableArray alloc] init] autorelease];   

//inserting the value from firstview to secondview before push
2ndController.record = record;
```

The first line doesn't do anything useful for you. It creates and initializes a new NSMutableArray and sets the record property to that new array.

But then in the very next line you set the same 'record' property again to a different object and so that array in the first line is no longer referenced. So you might as well not have ever created it.

That's not your issue exactly, but this comment was too big for a comment. :)